# qrDBRichview whitout paragraph format and font format

Tags: delphi, wrapper, delphi-2009, quickreports

I save my DBrichView( formatted justified) in a database and I need print in the quickreport.
I using "TRichView wrapper (RVQRControls) v3.0 for QuickReport", tQrDBRichview, but it isn't show the text formatted and also show with different font.

```
var
  sds1: TSQLDataSet;
  dsp1: TDataSetProvider;
  cds1: TClientDataSet;
  qrp1: TQuickRep;
  qrbDetailBand1: TQRBand;
  qrDBRvw1: TQRDBRichView;

  ...     
  with sds1 do
  begin
    CommandText := 
      'select  a.id_anot,  a.text,  a.cod_user from  anot a where  a.id_ANOT = 1977';   
  end;
  with dsp1 do
  begin
    Name := 'dsp1';
    DataSet := sds1;
  end;
  with cds1 do
  begin
    Name := 'cds1';
    ProviderName := 'dsp1';
  end;
  with qrp1 do
  begin
    Name := 'qrp1';
    DataSet := cds1;        
  end;
  with qrbDetailBand1 do
  begin
    Name := 'qrbDetailBand1';
    Parent := qrp1;
    BandType := rbDetail;
  end;      
  with qrDBRvw1 do
  begin
    Name := 'qrDBRvw1';
    Parent := qrbDetailBand1;
    NoMargins := True;
    DataField := 'TEXTO';
    DataSet := cds1;
  end;
  ...
```

How I resolve this?

Comment: You can start by eliminating about 99% of the code you posted which is not relevant to your question. We don't care about any of the other fields or controls that are created in your code, as they have no impact on the problem you describe. Why make us dig through all the noise that's not relevant to find the 10 lines or so that are?